# Trying to make a working subscribe form for my website

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, subscribe

I am trying to make a working subscribe form for my website.
The HTML part is not the problem for me, it's the back-end.
I am not master at PHP and JS but I tried to make it work.
When I run the code it says:
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at 35.232.170.255 Port 80

I tried to run it on php code runner of w3schools:

```
<?php 
    $message_sent = false;
    if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != ''){

        if( filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ){

            //submit the form
            $userName = $_POST['name'];
            $userEmail = $_POST['email'];
            $messageSubject = $_POST['subject'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];

            $to = 'drippostaff@gmail.com';
            $body = "";

            $body = "From: ".$userName. "\r\n";
            $body = "Email: ".$userEmail. "\r\n";
            $body = "Message: ".$message. "\r\n";

            mail($to,$messageSubject,$body);

            $message_sent = true;        
        }
            
        else{
            $invalid_class_name = "form-invalid";
        }


}

?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webform.css" media="all">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script>
        $(function() {
   
   $(".form-control").on('focus', function(){

       $(this).parents(".form-group").addClass('focused');

   });

   $(".form-control").on('blur', function(){

       $(this).parents(".form-group").removeClass('focused');

   });

});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="webform.php" method="POST" class="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="form-label">Your Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Jane Doe" tabindex="1" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="form-label">Your Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="jane@doe.com" tabindex="2" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subject" class="form-label">Subject</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Hello There!" tabindex="3" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message" class="form-label">Message</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" cols="50" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter Message..." tabindex="4"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Send Message!</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't have an SMTP server working on your local machine to get the `mail` function working.

**I recommend you use the** https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer, there you are going to find how to setup the SMTP credentials.

Example code using the library:

```
<?php
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.example.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'user@example.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'secret';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     //Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               //Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         //Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    //Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Edited: You can also set up the SMTP in your `php.ini`, you can follow this [Article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sending_emails.htm#:%7E:text=PHP%20makes%20use%20of%20mail,%2C%20message%2C%20headers%2C%20parameters%20%3B)